# FreeMarker template error: JSONArray wrapped into f.e.b.StringModel

Tags: java, junit, freemarker

i'm trying to send JSON object to my free marker, but i getting error while testing JUnit

here is my object

```
{
        "filename": "test",
        "orderId": "123435",
        "orderDate": "23.09.2020г.",
        "itemsCount": "4",
        "items": [
            {
                "itemName": "ТВ Приставка 400",
                "itemCount": "2 шт Х 400₽",
                "itemSum": "800.00"
            }
        ],
        "totalSumm": "3000.00"
    }
```

here is my error:

```
FreeMarker template error:
The value you try to list is an extended_hash+string (org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.util.json.JSONArray wrapped into f.e.b.StringModel), thus you must specify two loop variables after the "as"; one for the key, and another for the value, like <#... as k, v>).
```

how could i resolve it?

items is a arrays of JSON objects

Answer (score 0):

FreeMarker knows nothing about `org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.util.json.JSONArray`, so it doesn't see it as a list-like thing (as a sequence, as it's called in FTL). So you can do one of these:

- Using the `objectWrapper` `Configuration` setting, you teach FreeMarker how to treat `JSONArray` as a list. (You can find more about custom `ObjectWrapper`-s elsewhere.) Then you can just `#list` such objects, and use all the other operations applicable to sequences.
- Or, you call the Java API-s of `JSONArray` from the template. That will be less convenient of course, but requires no prior investment.